# Why is MT65xx Preloader a network interface on my Mac

Tags: network, wifi, memory, airport

I've been trying to figure out why my network adapter kext is chewing up so much memory and just noticed this in my settings > network interfaces

`MT65xx preloader`

Anyone know what this is?  Looks like some sort of Android interface, but I don't use anything like that.

Could this be related to, or possibly an indication of a system compromise to a virus, etc?

[image]

Answer (score 12):

MT65xx preloaded is related to MediaTek/Android devices Drivers,,seems like you where tethering an Android device of which is likely to be of MediaTek chipset of which won't work on Mac, but you can still use the [HoRNDIS](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwir7-TU_tTQAhUDrRoKHSiEAvIQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjoshuawise.com%2Fhorndis&usg=AFQjCNEUGFMvyPi0z8Ehpmq84OPcR9TrwA&sig2=Bv_uGJ8VQo-K4UeLtwaQDA) driver as an alternative.

You can just Delete it and it will bring no problem